# Regex to find date string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have many sites on which I need to find the date, all of these sites have different templates, so I need a regular expression, here are examples of how dates are displayed on these sites:

```
Saturday, March 24, 2007
1 JANUARY 2016
31st December 2016
23 Agustus 2019
2012年5月7日 
August 23, 2019
```

I tried to do something like this:

```py
re.search(r"((\w+\s\w+(,\s|\s)\w+)|(\w+[0-9]\w))", text)
```

But during the test, I got this:

```
2014 jQuery Foundation
81vy4jRyxBHyxIhY67E
```

How to write a regular expression in my case?

Comment: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5

Comment: I found a better solution than regex:
[htmldate](https://pypi.org/project/htmldate/)

Answer (score 3):

You might have to write some custom expressions, then use alternation, maybe a bit similar to:

```
^[A-Z][A-Za-z]+[\s,]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]+[\s,]*\d+[\s,]*\d{4}|\d+[A-Za-z]*[\s,]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]+[\s,]*\d{4}|[A-Z][A-Za-z]*[\s,]*\d+[\s,]*\d{4}|\d{4}\D+\d+\D+\d+\D+$
```

which would likely fail for some instances, which you might want to adjust for. It'd be much better to add much more boundaries.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AOveOI/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/AOveOI/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"^[A-Z][A-Za-z]+[\s,]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]+[\s,]*\d+[\s,]*\d{4}|\d+[A-Za-z]*[\s,]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]+[\s,]*\d{4}|[A-Z][A-Za-z]*[\s,]*\d+[\s,]*\d{4}|\d{4}\D+\d+\D+\d+\D+$"

test_str = """
Saturday, March 24, 2007
1 JANUARY 2016
31st December 2016
23 Agustus 2019
2012年5月7日 
August 23, 2019

2014 jQuery Foundation
81vy4jRyxBHyxIhY67E

"""
print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.M))
```

#### Output

```
['Saturday, March 24, 2007', '1 JANUARY 2016', '31st December 2016', '23 Agustus 2019', '2012年5月7日 ', 'August 23, 2019']
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: @Emma now this find ```D15483```

Comment: @Emma and i dont need to get ```Saturday,``` in outp